# REST Service not responding

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat

I have build a rest service using tomcat and jersey.

The used web.xml contains only:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The pom.xml file contains:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is part of the java file I use as the implementation of the service:

```
@Path("/light")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is requested
  @GET
  @Path("/state/")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String getStateOfLights() {
    return "hi";//getLightsStateAsJSON();
  }
}
```

[image: This is my file layout]

The index.html file directly under the WebContent directory is reachable through localhost:8080/ha/index.html. This is working as expected.

If I want to test my rest service I call: http://localhost:8080/ha/rest/light/state/
And what do I get: HTTP Status 404: Not found

What am I missing here?

This is the server log :

```
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ha' did not find a matching property.
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent 
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/werner/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init 
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init 
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load 
INFO: Initialization processed in 620 ms
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:33 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom 
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [548] milliseconds.
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start 
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start 
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 25, 2015 7:07:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2641 ms
```

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8080/rest/light/state/`? Your webservice isn't deployed in your `ha` folder.

Comment: Isn't that what I have written? Or do you mean to say that the used URL is wrong?

Comment: Corrected my post. Don't add `ha` to the URL. The Servlet Container is mapped to `/rest`, your resource to `/light` and the method to `/state`, so the final url should be `/rest/light/state/`

Comment: Ok. Yes I tried that too. Same result. HTTP Status 404

Comment: Please post the startup log of the server.

Comment: Try to access http://localhost:8080/rest/application.wadl or http://localhost:8080/application.wadl etc. You should get a description of the available REST endpoints if you figure out the correct deployment root.

Comment: Thomas Schmidt: I added the logging to the post. I can't find the start of my ha application in the log file....

Comment: jkbkot: Both give me HTTP Status 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `<init-param>` in your web.xml. it should be:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
  <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example</param-value> <!-- where com.example.Hello is your Hello class -->
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Replace `com.example` with the package of your `Hello` class.